# Delete Double Pointer for the CCSprite?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am using double pointer for the CCSprite. For the pointer to pointer I am doing new and for then creating then using cocos2d usual method create 
How should I delete the double pointer in following case

```
 CCSprite **mCBg;

 mCBg = new CCSprite*[mNumberBackgound];

//for loop for creating sprites 
 mCBgLayer[i]= CCSprite::create("Sprites/level1.png");
```

Since Create automatically adds to the memory pool

What about the Objects created using 'new' how to delete them in destructor

```
 if(mCBg)
{
    CC_SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY(mCBgLayer);
}
```

If I do this I get crash in destructor 
Please give answer with explanation. So i can understand the memory management of cocos2d-x

Comment: Double-pointer usage almost always implies a problem with your design, or you're trying to be "too clever". Try to find a solution that doesn't need a double pointer, regardless of what the issue is you're having here.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D  : Surely, I will try to find a solution that doesn't need double pointer

Comment: A "double pointer" is not a thing in C++. What you're playing with here is a "pointer to pointer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocos2d-x use `Reference Count` and `AutoReleasePool` to manage memory.

The function `CCSprite::create()` 's implementation used `autorelease()`.You do not need to release the memory, or the reference count will be smaller than 0;More detail see:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Reference_Count_and_AutoReleasePool_in_Cocos2d-x